# Programatically dismiss spreadsheet.toast & configure height and width?

Tags: google-apps-script

How could I dismiss the toast?

Can I control the height and the width or both?

```
spreadsheet.toast("Done. Task has completed.", "Status", -1);
```

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing the developer API, there doesn't seem to be a way to manually adjust the size of the toast.  By setting the last part to -1, you're telling the toast not to go away until you manually dismiss it.

If you wish to only display it for a certain amount of time, set a time in seconds for how long you wish to display, or leave it out for it to dismiss after 5 seconds.

```
//Timeout in 5 seconds
spreadsheet.toast("Done. Task has completed.", "Status");

//Timeout in 2 seconds
spreadsheet.toast("Done. Task has completed.", "Status", 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the note. Yeah, I couldn't find anything about sizing anywhere either. I get the Timeout function but am looking for some way to dismiss it from within the script just like you clicked the "x" to close it.

Comment: Hmm, I'm personally not sure if there is a way to do that.  Out of curiosity, what is your reasoning behind wanting to do that?

Comment: So I can dismiss it if I pop a browser message box (or something else) triggered by some other event which would make the toast either irrelevant or somewhat redundant.

Answer (score 2):

One ugly, hacky way to do it is:

```
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("", "", 0.01);
```

The timeoutSeconds parameter can take floats. You will still see a blank toast popping up, but it will disappear right away.